# R version of splitting dataset using macro in SAS

Tags: r, macros, sas

I am new to using R and have previously been using SAS for all my work. I'm struggling to convert some SAS logic into R and would really appreciate some help with this. In SAS, I can use macros to split up a dataset and keep specific variables and rename the resulting datasets according to the variables. For example:

```
%macro data_split (field);
    data data_out_&field. (keep = policy_number date &field.);
    set my_data;
    run;
%mend;
%data_split(area1);
%data_split(surname);
%data_split(dob);
```

/*

The code will produce three datasets:
    data_out_area1
    data_out_surname
    data_out_dob
All three datasets will have the variables 'policy_number' and 'date' in them as suggested by the keep statement.
Plus, each dataset will have ONE additional variable 'area1', 'surname' and 'dob' respectively.
The output datasets have been suffixed with the variable name used in the macro "data_split".

*/

In R, I can do the following:

```
data_out_area1 <- mydata$area1
data_out_surname <- mydata$surname
data_out_dob <- mydata$dob
```

However, I lose the column names when doing this. Also, and perhaps more importantly, if I have a hundred variables I want to avoid writing out these statements a hundred times... is there a way for me to loop through the data frame and create a hundred new datasets?

Comment: If you show reproducible income and expected output (and reaons behind it) you will get good answers, bu only small subset of R programmers are fluent in SAS.

Comment: `cols <- c("hp", "drat", "am")`; `lyst <- lapply(cols, function(x)mtcars[,c("cyl","mpg",x)]);
names(lyst) <- paste0("data_out_",cols)` , Is this what you are looking for, one can create a list object and add the elements of dataframes, for example using `mtcars` data you can do above. Print the `lyst` and see if you want to do something like that

Comment: Just use named indexing for a few variables: `data_out_area1 <- mydata["area1"]` and `data_out_surname <- mydata["surname"]`. Use @PKumar's suggestion for many